# The case of the missing space in migration banners

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, migration, post-notice

The migration banner has lost the space between its sentences:

[image: Blue migration notice/banner, stating: "This question was migrated from Stack Overflow because it can be answered on Meta Stack Overflow.Migrated 4 mins ago."]

This happens in both sides, on the target site (as shown above) and on the original site:

[image: Blue migration notice/banner, stating: "This question was migrated to Meta Stack Overflow, our site for discussion, support, and feature requests for this site.Migrated 7 mins ago by some users whose names are not important."]

Please put the space back!

Technically speaking, the problem is almost certainly because these two sentences are separate tags in the HTML, so the back-end process that is generating them doesn't know to insert a space between HTML elements (and arguably shouldn't). Here is the HTML as it is currently rendered on the target site:

```html
<div class="flex--item fl1 lh-lg">
This question was <a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work">migrated</a> from Stack Overflow because it can be answered on Meta Stack Overflow.<a href="https://example.com">Migrated</a> <span title="Mar 9 at 10:21"><span title="2023-03-09 10:21:13Z" class="relativetime">4 mins ago</span></span>.                    </div>
```

There are some extra spaces there at the end you can steal. :-)

Comment: Ah yes, the case of the missing space budget, right alongside the case of missing CGI budget for collective icons

Comment: At least Stack Overflow is an US based company, so they can ask the Space Force if they can help.

Comment: This also affects bounty notices, [as reported on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387395).

Comment: And, seemingly, [suggested edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423591/208273).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue! It is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like it's fixed in all the banners (I checked migration and bounty notices but I don't have a suggested edit handy); is that correct?

Comment: The [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387395/1099857) and [suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387529/1099857) reports were both marked status-completed on MSE @RyanM

Comment: Thank you @HenryEcker! Yes, it's fixed in all banners.

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I can confirm and am able to reproduce this bug. I have also found this bug in a different place, when I submit an edit for approval:

> Thanks for submitting an edit.It is only visible to you until it’s been approved by trusted community members.

The grammar error is the one missing space between `edit` and `It`.

Comment: And for bounties too. "The bounty expires in 45 minutes. Answers to this question are eligible for a +100 reputation bounty.charlie wants to draw more attention to this question."

Comment: Both of those should be fixed now as well.