# Missing space after submitting suggested edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, typographical-error, whitespace

When I submit an edit for approval, this is what I see:

> Thanks for submitting an edit.It is only visible to you until it’s been [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34010769) by trusted community members.

The grammar error is the one missing space between `edit` and `It`.

Comment: Related: [The case of the missing space](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423569/the-case-of-the-missing-space)

Comment: It seems that you are reporting effectively the same bug; the fact that there "aren't any answers" on the other Meta question simply indicates that there isn't anything to say about it yet (e.g. staff hasn't acknowledged or assessed the bug report yet). That being the case... what are we supposed to be able to tell you here? If we had an "answer" for this, it would have already been written there.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Oh, ok.  Should I delete my question then?

Comment: Ehhhhhh, I'd leave it up.  It's a different site feature, so it's probably different code, so it's probably helpful to document each of the cases where it's happening separately (as we learned during the Great HTML Escaping Problems of 2022).  Although the comments linking them to each other are helpful. (also, I edited Hans's comment to clarify that it's just linking a related bug; hopefully Hans doesn't mind)

Comment: You could, at your option, add this as an _answer_ to that question instead of a new question (though the new question is fine, too), and we could keep a collection of them all there.  Although hopefully it's just a small number of them and it won't be much of a collection.

Comment: @RyanM **"add this as an answer to that question"**.  Why post an answer? I feel it would be more appropriate to add this as an comment, as you're not answering the question.

Comment: I don't have a great answer to that other than "meta is kind of a weird use of a Q&A engine to begin with, and answers are the best way we've got to add substantive new information about a problem (especially because they can have images, edits to track the status, etc.)."

Comment: You can *make* it an answer to the question: "I can confirm/am able to reproduce this bug. I have *also* found this bug in a different context..." But yeah, like Ryan says, this is just common convention on Meta sites, which abuse the Q&A engine for things that aren't strictly Q&A.

Comment: More "annoying"/confusing with that Msg is the use of "*trusted community members*" which doesn't mean anything and certainly not "*[trusted users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)*" (20k-Rep) but actually "*users with the [edit posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege*" (2k-Rep).

Comment: It means that they're trusted with the privilege of reviewing suggested edits, @chivracq. The name "trusted users" for the 20k rep privilege package is just a poorly-chosen, non-descriptive name.

Comment: @CodyGray, yeah well, there is still "stg" weird and completely confusing with the whole 'Edit' Workflow, at least for Tag Wikis ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/6135)) as the "*tag wiki edit privileges*" words in the "*You do not yet have [tag wiki edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).*" sentence do link to the 'trusted user' Privilege (20k-Rep), while Users with "only" 5k-Rep and the '[approve tag wiki edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)' Privilege can already approve those Edits...

Comment: @RyanM Done! I've posted this as an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423595/20585541) to the [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423569/the-case-of-the-missing-space).

Comment: Sounds good!  I'll mark this one as a duplicate to point everyone to that one.

Comment: Same bug for bounties.