# Missing space in bounty text

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, user-interface

I opened a bounty on my question [Setting dependencies between mapped Airflow tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76168010/1445366). There is a missing space between the second and third bounty description sentences:

> [image: screenshot of bounty text with missing space between sentences.]

I observed it in two different browsers and it appears to be included in the HTML source:

```html
eligible for a <span class="s-badge s-badge__bounty d-inline px4 py2 ba bc-transparent 
bar-sm fs-caption va-middle">+500</span> reputation bounty.<a 
href="/users/1445366/aaron-brager">Aaron Brager</a> wants to <b>draw more attention</b> 
to this question:
```

Comment: While quite similar to "[The case of the missing space in migration banners](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423569/3773011)", it's unclear if the issues are, in fact, the same bug, rather than two things in similar areas of the display. IMO, it's better to error on the side of letting SE know about both issues and allow the developers check to see if it's really the same code, or not.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: "[Missing space in bounty notice on a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387395/271271)"

Comment: Per [the corresponding bug report on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387395/335251), the missing space has been found – this issue is now fixed.

Comment: This is now confirmed to have been same issue, and it has now been fixed, so I'm marking it as a duplicate to make the history a bit easier to track for future reference.